# Fast way to determine if string is a JSON number

Tags: c++, json

The check must not user C++11 features or additional libraries e.g. Boost, Regex etc. I came up with the following solution. No pretty but working. Does it get more elegant and/or faster from here?

```
bool isJsonNumber(const std::string& text)
{
    if(text.empty()) return false;

    bool foundE = false;
    bool foundESign = false;
    bool leadingZero = false;
    bool lastIsDigit = false;
    bool foundDot = false;

    for(uint32_t i=0; i < text.length(); ++i)
    {
        const unsigned char c = text[i];

        lastIsDigit = false;
        const bool currIsNoDigit = (c < '0' || c > '9');

        if(i == 0)
        {
            if(currIsNoDigit && c != '-' ) return false;
            if(c == '0') leadingZero = true;
            if(c != '-') lastIsDigit = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if(leadingZero)
            {
                leadingZero = false;
                if(c != '.') return false;
                foundDot = true;
            }
            else if(c == '.')
            {
                if(foundDot) return false;
                foundDot = true;
            }
            else if(c == 'e' || c == 'E')
            {
                if(foundE) return false;
                foundE = true;
            }
            else if(foundE && !foundESign)
            {
                if(currIsNoDigit && c != '-' && c != '+') return false;
                if(c == '+' || c == '-')
                {
                    foundESign = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    lastIsDigit = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foundESign = false;
                if(currIsNoDigit) return false;
                lastIsDigit = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if(lastIsDigit == false) return false;

    return true;
}
```

The use case is a small embedded server that recieves huge CSV files and anwsers  clients with portions in JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be easier to use [`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof):

```
size_t endpos;
std::stod(text, &endpos);

if (endpos != text.length())
{
    // Not a number
}
else
{
    // A number
}
```

---

If you don't have `std::stod`, as it's a C++11 feature, you could do something similar with [`std::strtod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof).

---

If you want to disallow `INFINITY` or `NAN` or hexadecimal floating point values, it's as easy as checking that the second or third character in the string is not a letter:

```
if ((text.length() > 2 && std::isalpha(text[1])) ||
    (text.length() > 3 && std::isalpha(text[2])))
{
    // Not a number
}
```

For "larger" numnbers there always `std::stold` or `std::strtold`. However if you want arbitrarily sized numbers then either do as you do now or use a library such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) ([`mpf_set_str`](http://gmplib.org/manual/Assigning-Floats.html#Assigning-Floats) seems like a good function for this).

Comment: The JSON spec describes numbers of arbitrary size that can exceed the size of a double. Also Infinity and NaN are no allowed values for numbers, same for hexa-decimal numbers. also std::stod is C++11

Comment: Function std::strtod is not appropriate to validate a JSON number. The spec can be found in RFC 4627. The OP's version is (probably) OK. (Assuming there are corresponding unit tests ;)  )